# Is this a valid change of variables?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, wave-equation, change-of-variable

We are solving for the sound wave caused by the motion of a spherical piston. In a spherically symmetric case, the classical wave equation reads:
$$\phi_{tt}=a_0^2\Big(\phi_{rr}+\frac{2\phi_r}{r}\Big),\tag{1}$$
where $\phi$ is the velocity potential. The general solution for the forward moving wave is given by:
$$\phi=\frac{1}{r}f(r-a_0t),$$
where $a_0$ is the constant speed of sound. The radial velocity $u$ is therefore:
$$u=\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial r}=\frac{1}{r^2}f(r-a_0t) - \frac{1}{r}f'(r-a_0t).$$
If the piston motion is given by $R=R(t)$, then using the boundary condition for velocity at the piston $u(R(t),t)=dR/dt$, we get from the previous equation:
$$\dot{R}=\frac{1}{R^2}f(R-a_0t) - \frac{1}{R}f'(R-a_0t),\tag{2}$$
which is a first-order ordinary differential equation that we can solve for $f$.

Well so it goes. However, the one thing I find annoying about this is the last equation. Namely, the term $f'(R-a_0t)$ is not the derivative of $f$ w.r.t $(R-a_0t)$, but rather the derivative of $f$ w.r.t $(r-a_0t)$, evaluated at $r=R$. Thus, can we solve this as an ODE even though the differentiation is not made w.r.t the same independent variable of the equation?

**Edit:** Replying to the comment by Mattos, $\phi$ represents the general form of a wave transported in the positive $r$ direction (i.e radially outwards), and it can be easily shown that it satisfies the wave equation, namely:
$$\phi_t=-\frac{a_0}{r}f'(r-a_0t),$$
$$\phi_{tt}=\frac{a_0^2}{r}f''(r-a_0t),$$
$$\phi_r=\frac{1}{r}f'(r-a_0t) - \frac{1}{r^2}f(r-a_0t),$$
$$\phi_{rr}= \frac{1}{r}f''(r-a_0t)-\frac{2}{r^2}f'(r-a_0t)+\frac{2}{r^3}f(r-a_0t),$$
and substituting these values into equation (1) yields
$$\frac{a_0^2}{r}f''(r-a_0t)=\frac{a_0^2}{r}f''(r-a_0t),$$
thus satisfying the equation.

As for the other question, since $R(t)$ is given, equation (2) can be solved for $f$ up to a constant.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'the general solution for the forward moving wave is $\dots$', the solution $\phi$ doesn't satisfy your PDE. Also, I don't see how you can solve the equation for $f$. The form of $f$ should have been determined from the boundary and initial conditions.

Comment: @mattos please see the edit

Comment: My apologies, ignore what I said. I totally missed the fact that the solution was $f/\color{red}r$, not $f$. This is why I don't do maths at 3am. I'll have a look at your question in the morning if no one has answered it already